# CAD (Solidworks): how to extrude as the width along a ramp changes

Tags: modeling, cad, solidworks, 3d-modelling

I'm quite new to CAD/Solidworks, and am having a trouble understanding how exactly I would model the figure shown in the diagram.

[image: Figure 1]

As circled, the top part of the ramp has a width of 0.38, and towards the bottom, the width becomes 0.25. Are there any tools I can use to make the "width" or extrude length of the figure change gradually along the slope? Also, it's not very clear to me where exactly on the ramp the width becomes 0.25; would I just assume that it measures 0.25 at the very end of the slope, or would I just approximate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the ramp is 0.25 period. It doesn't change at the top. The circled 0.38 is the width of the hidden tab symmetrical to the other 0.38 width tab on the other side.

For that matter, the thickness of every features on this particular part is 0.25 everywhere.